# Redirect does not redirect to home page instead redirects to setup page with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I want to redirect homepage to setup page after redux action compleated. App.js Code is

```
const companyDetails = useSelector((state) => state.companyDetails);
const { loading, error, company } = companyDetails;
useEffect(() => {
  if (!company) {
    dispatch(detailsCompany());
  }
}, [dispatch, company]);
return loading ? (
  <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
  ) : error ? (
  <MessageBox variant="success">{error}</MessageBox>
  ) : (
  ...otherRoutes
   <Route path="/" exact>
      {company ? (
        userInfo?.isAdmin ? (
          <DashboardScreen />
        ) : (
          <HomeScreen />
        )
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/setup" />
      )}
    </Route>
)
```

After redux action completed, company variable has value but it is redirected to setup page instead home page or dashboard.

Comment: Is the function *detailsCompany()* written using redux-thunk?

Comment: yes. Redux-thunk is used to write detailsCompany()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component on the initial render does not have the company field defined. So this will go to the code path that performs the redirect even before the details of the company are fetched.

Even if the company details completed fetching the page has already been redirected.One of the ways to handle this is

Assuming that the `detailsCompany()` is something like this

```
function detailsCompany(){
  return dispatch=>{
    return someApi.getCompanyDetails().then(()=>{//do something})
                                      .catch(()=>{//do something})
}
```

This function if it returns a resolved promise then the useEffect can be rewritten as

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!company) {
    dispatch(detailsCompany()).then(()=>{//do what is needed})
                              .catch(performRedirect)
  }
}, [dispatch, company]);
```

This ensures if the company details are not able to be fetched then a redirect will happen.

In order to perform the redirect a separate state can be kept like

```
const [redirect,setRedirect] = useState(false);
```

So the perform redirect function will be like

```
const performRedirect = ()=>setRedirect(true)
```

The redirect should tag should be used based on the value of this state

```
 {!redirect?(company ? (
    userInfo?.isAdmin ? (
      <DashboardScreen />
    ) : (
      <HomeScreen />
    )
  )):(
    <Redirect to="/setup" />
  )}
```

}

if the state redirect is false the second part will not be executed.

Comment: Thanks for your help sir. Slightly I changed your code concept. It works now. instead of set values in catch() . I am defining variable in action. like  payload: {
        company: data.company[0],
        redirectTo: data.company[0] ? '/' : '/setup',
      },. and check for that value in router like your code. Thank You sir